Which DC do the PowerShell ActiveDirectory cmdlets use if none is specified?
I have a PowerShell script which runs under a scheduled task.  It runs various cmdlets from the ActiveDirectory module under PowerShell 5.1 on a Server 2016 box.  It has run okay for months.  This morning, it failed with:
+         $domain = Get-ADDomain
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (NETDOM:ADDomain) [Get-ADDomain], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8251,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADDomain

I would like to know which DC it was trying to contact so I can investigate.  Obviously, it is too late for this run but I was planning to add a line before this command to log the DC being used to aid future investigations.
[I have assumed the module must pick a DC and keep on using it otherwise it might write an update to one DC and then try to read it back from another DC before replication has completed.]
I have tried searching the documentation for ActiveDirectory and a general internet search to no avail.

As you've stated, this isn't something documented. It's very likely it will use the first one it finds, (Get-PSDrive AD).Root is //RootDSE/ so pressumably it uses (Get-ADRootDSE).serverName or (Get-ADRootDSE).dnsHostName for the rest of the session

One option you could try is to first find the name of a DC, and then pass that explicitely to your command rather than letting it detect/handle that itself. Eg:
$dc = Get-ADDomainController -discover -domain mydomain -forcediscover | Select-Object -expandproperty hostname
$domain = Get-ADDomain -server $dc

So $dc contains the reference to a specific domain controller on your network, and you then know you're passing the query to that DC when you include the -server $dc parameter.
That also means you can 1) save the current value of $dc to your log file, and 2) determine whether the issue is with querying that particular DC, or more generally with finding a DC to query.
I'm not 100% sure that once the AD module has found a DC that it will keep using that one, but by expressly telling the AD commands which DC to use you'll also rule out the possibility of it sending you to multiple DCs during your script run.
